# To find same value in different rows and different columns (SQL)

Tags: sql-server

Apologies,  I have missed out one condition earlier (Added in *Italic* and **bold**)

I have a table with a few thousand rows, and I would like to extract texts from certain columns if there are matching values in different columns.

For example:

| A | B | C | D | ***E*** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| teeth | MrA | 123 | ABC | ***$128*** |
| nose | MrB | CDE | 789 | ***$100*** |
| hand | MrC | ABC | 456 | ***$128*** |
| eye | MrD | EFG | 789 | ***$110*** |

The expected outcome is if any value of C = D or vice versa, ***and with same E value***, then the query should return values from column A & column B or the whole row.

Results would be:

| A | B | C | D | ***E*** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| teeth | MrA | 123 | ABC | ***$128*** |
| hand | MrC | ABC | 456 | ***$128*** |

as C match with D on ABC ***and E = $128 which is same for both rows***.

The query that I have tried thus far can only return the value if C & D have same value in same row. Appreciate help on this, thanks!

Comment: SELECT *
FROM MyTable as t1
INNER JOIN MyTable as t2
ON t1.C = t2.D OR t1.A = t2.B

Comment: Adding to @SebastianS's comment, you also need to exclude the current row based on the primary key due to the self join. Assuming the primary key is a composite key on A and B: `AND t1.A <> t2.A AND t1.B <> t2.B`.

Comment: FYI *changing* your question after you have received answers is frowned upon; if you need to, you should ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use `exists`

```
select * 
from t
where exists (select * from t t2 where t.c=t2.d or t.d=t2.c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than Stu's answer, you can also use Cross join but you have to watch out for query performance.

```
select t2.* --or t.*
from Trt t
cross join Trt t2
where t.C = t2.D or t.D = t2.C;
```

Comment: Thank you! This do return duplicated rows but can be solved by adding distinct function so it works!